# How to execute chrome extension script before other scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to execute the JavaScript from my chrome extension before any other script from the page is executed (including async scripts).
I tried to use the "run_at" attribute in the manifest, but none of the options worked.

Comment: The question lacks specifics ([MCVE](/help/mcve)) so I can only guess you're trying to run code in page context, in which case you need to use textContent approach, see method 2 in [this answer](/a/9517879). And naturally you'll also need `"run_at": "document_start"`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry that this questions lacks the specifics. I'll try to do better next time. But can I be sure, that the injected script will be executed first?

Comment: Uhm, my comment above explains it already.

Comment: is that possible with v3? I am trying to inject a script to change the navigator.language (before the react javascript is executed)